# How often does $p^k$ divide the Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

I would like to know about the Fibonacci numbers $F_n = 1,1,2,3,5,8, \dots$ 
in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

$$ \mathbb{P}[p^k \text{ divides }  F_n ] =  \frac{\#\{1 \leq n\leq N:  F_n \equiv 0 \mod p^k \} }{N} $$

For various primes, $p$ and $N \to \infty$ does this have a limit in explicit form?

This amounts to just looking at the Fibonacci sequence $F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n-1}$ over all prime powers $p^k$ at once.  I am asking how often is it $0$ ?

---

Possibly related:

- [Does every prime divide some Fibonacci number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695979/does-every-prime-divide-some-fibonacci-number)
- [Profinite and p-adic interpolation of Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310397/profinite-and-p-adic-interpolation-of-fibonacci-numbers)
- [Fibonacci modular results](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results)

---

In light of all this, perhaps I should be asking for the order of $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.  The smallest number $k$ such that $(\tfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^k = 1 \text{ mod }p$

Comment: This limit certainly must exist due to the existence of a [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) modulo every integer.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How about a quantitative result?

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively easy to show that the Fibonacci sequence must be *eventually* periodic [modulo any integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695979/does-every-prime-divide-some-fibonacci-number).  From there, it suffices to take the repeating string of integers and count the zeros.

There seems to be a way to [find the period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period#Number_theory) modulo $p^k$, but I do not know of any way to go about counting the zeros except directly.

Comment: see http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/fib.htm

Comment: @WillJagy So my question is related to the order of the Golden ration $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ modulo $p^k$.  We know $ (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic but not the order of any particular element...